# How do I specify my data in my column to only produce odd values?

Tags: postgresql

The data in my column is numeric and I want to permanently change the numeric data to only contain odd values.
For example if I have the data in the column as 101331, 107332, 101333, 101334 I only want the updated table to contain 107331 and 101333.

| Original Column | New Column |
| --- | --- |
| 101331 | 101331 |
| 107332 | 101333 |
| 101333 |  |
| 101334 |  |

Comment: What happened to 101331?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want to select all the odd values.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (original_column % 2) = 1;
```

Or, if you are trying to delete the even rows

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE (original_column % 2) = 0;
```